# Context-registered SMS receiver

Tags: nativescript

```
const intentFilter = new android.content.IntentFilter(
    android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED
);
application.android.registerBroadcastReceiver(intentFilter, function(
    context,
    intent
) {
    console.log('Text has been received.');
});
```

Hi I'm trying to create this in code but I am struggling to say the least!

Answer (score -1):

I slept on it, and in a dream the following came to me:

```
const intentFilter = 'android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED';
application.android.registerBroadcastReceiver(intentFilter, function(
    context,
    intent
) {
    console.log('Text has been received.');
});
```